# Can speed time on my computer and localhost for testing php script

Tags: php, performance, time, localhost

Can I to hasten time on my computer or xampp server in my computer to test the my php script whether it is working properly ?

It should that at the expiration of the server create a new table in phpmyadmin and in user panel..

Can and how?

Comment: .. what? Speed up.. time?

Comment: Yes.. I need to speed up the time to test the script..
The script should be in the expiry date of creating a new table for renewal / payment server

-a few days before the expiry of this should happen